# iOS Pull To Refresh Not Working on Specific Devices like iPhone X

Tags: objective-c, iphone, pull-to-refresh, iphone-x, uirefreshcontrol

I am using pull to refresh for usual data refresh on a tableview.

Here is my code

```
-(void)addUIRefreshControl{

    //Instantiate and Configure Refresh Control

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]; // initialize refresh control
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor appBaseColor]; // set tint color
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(refreshAPI)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; // add target

    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl]; // add the refresh control

}

-(void)refreshAPI{

    if ([APP_DELEGATE isNetAvailable]) {
        [self fetchAPI];
    }else{
        if (self.refreshControl) {
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; //end refreshing
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on iOS Devices & Simulator except for iPhone X. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: move refreshcontrol to superview in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

Is your app iOS 10 & newer only?  If so, you should be using your commented out line:

```
- (void)addUIRefreshControl{
    UIRefreshControl * refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init]; // initialize refresh control
    refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor appBaseColor]; // set tint color
    refreshControl addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(refreshAPI)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; // add target
    if (self.tableView != NULL) {
        // tableView will have a strong reference (and retain) refreshControl ; no need to have it be its own property
        self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        NSLog(@"suprise!  self.tableView is null");
    }
}
```

And you should always call "endRefreshing" when the value changes (or updates).  Before, you were calling only if `isNetAvailable` was false.

```
-(void)refreshAPI{

    if ([APP_DELEGATE isNetAvailable]) {
        [self fetchAPI];
    }

    [self.tableView.refreshControl endRefreshing]; //end refreshing
}
```

Comment: Hi Micheal, I am calling endRefreshing inside my API Callbacks.

Comment: is that API callback not included in the example code you put up in your original question?

Comment: No, Micheal, It's inside the fetchAPI method. And I tried your code as well. But it still doesn't work for iPhone X. Its working perfect for other devices. It's really strange

Comment: if you set breakpoints in Xcode, do `refreshAPI` and `fetchAPI` get called?  Can you put a breakpoint at `endRefreshing` and does it hit, on an iPhoneX?

Comment: No, Micheal, the selector method does not get called at all. I keep on dragging the screen halfway down, but it simply does not do anything.

Comment: Does the refresh control even appear?

Comment: Yes it appears normally, but On dragging it rotates to a certain angle but it does not provide the vibration feedback or calls out its selector method.